# как сделать круглую обрезку изображения в OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2017

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    String imageName("../E30.jpg"); // by default
    Mat image;

    image = imread(imageName, IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file
    if (image.empty())                      // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int startX = 100, startY = 100, width = 200, height = 200;

    Mat ROI(image, Rect(startX, startY, width, height));

    Mat croppedImage;

    // Copy the data into new matrix
    ROI.copyTo(croppedImage);

    //imwrite("newImage.png", croppedImage);
    namedWindow("original", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    namedWindow("cropped", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("original", image);
    imshow("cropped", croppedImage);                // Show our image inside it.
    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0
}
```

Это квадратная обрезка . Что надо изменить чтобы получить круглую в данном коде?

Answer (score 0):

У `copyTo()` вторым аргументом идёт матрица с маской, которую можно использовать для копирования данных исходного изображения произвольной формы:

```
cv::Mat msk_mat = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8U);
cv::circle(msk_mat, cv::Point(width/2,height/2)
    , std::min(width,height), cv::Scalar::all(255), -1);

cv::Mat crop_mat;
image(cv::Rect(startX,startY,width,height))
    .copyTo(crop_mat, msk_mat);
```